# Get Wikidata entity revision history via SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to programatically access the revision history of wikidata entities (e.g., what you can see [here](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Q2&action=history) in the wikidata web frontend). Is there any way getting this information from the wikidata sparql endpoint?

If not, is there any other way to accessing the history through an API?

Comment: Use [MWAPI](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual/MWAPI) like [this](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Request_a_query#Usage_history_for_multiple_properties_in_one_query) or pure [API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Revisions).

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: See also https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:History_Query_Service

Comment: Thanks for the update!